# canActivated in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I create some application in angular 2 with typescript and add authentification.

I create authguard for my routing file:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

public router: Router;
public serverThisLogin: ServerDataComponent;

constructor(router: Router) {
    this.router = router;
}

public canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.serverThisLogin.isLogin)  {
        return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
    return false;
}
}
```

And this is `isLogin()` function:

```
 public isLogin (username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
     return this.http.post( authURL + loginURL,
                             JSON.stringify({  password, username }))
     .map((response: Response) => {
         if (response.status === 200) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     });
 }
```

I add authguard in my route file:

```
{ canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: LaskComponent, path: "table_per" }
```

And now, when i load this page `localhost/table_per` i have this error: 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLogin' of undefined`.
I really understand why it happens.

Comment: you don't inject a ServerDataComponent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to inject the service to be able to use it, take profit of Typescript possibility to use the DI container properly:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

public router: Router;
public serverThisLogin: ServerDataComponent;

constructor(private router: Router, private serviveThisLogin: ServerDataComponent) {}

public canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.serverThisLogin.isLogin) {
        return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
    return false;
    }
}
```

Also, you could simplify your condition from this:

```
if (response.status === 200) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
```

To this:

```
return response.status === 200;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! But unfortunelly, navegate to /login form doesnt work (